# scikit learn documentation in PDF

Tags: python-2.7, pdf, scikit-learn, html-to-pdf

Does anyone have any idea how I can get the scikit learn documentation (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/documentation.html) specifically the user guide, tutorials and examples, in PDF format?

If they are not readily available, is there a way to convert them to PDF programmatically? I looked around for html to pdf conversion api services but none of them is free...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here http://sourceforge.net/projects/scikit-learn/files/documentation/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

User docs can be found here http://sourceforge.net/projects/scikit-learn/files/documentation/ also, the older versions.

Also, you can create up-to-date offline HTML docs from Github https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/master/doc

To generate the full web page, including
the example gallery (this might take a while):

```
make html
```

Or, if you'd rather not build the example gallery:

```
make html-noplot
```

That should create all the doc in directory _build/html

To build the PDF manual, run

```
make latexpdf
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks. I wish they would include all this information on the main page (or perhaps they did and I missed it).

Comment: Never mind. It's there, right on the main page :-) http://scikit-learn.org/stable/support.html#documentation-resources

Answer (score 0):

@John Galt's answer is already great for this. For a generic solution of converting a html tree to pdf, see [this SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/219502/231052):

> I use wget to recursively download websites (normally online html
>   manuals) then once I have the html all in a folder I convert to the
>   format of my choice using [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/).

Answer (score 0):

According to:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/master/doc

more recent versions are here:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.github.io

in 0.1x/_downloads/scikit-learn-docs.pdf.

e.g. the most recent as of today is:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.github.io/blob/master/0.19/_downloads/scikit-learn-docs.pdf